# FullCalendar - flexible time range for day\week agenda

Tags: fullcalendar

I was trying to play with the minTime and the maxTime, I need the hours range to be from 6:00am untill 5:30am.

Unfortunately this is not possible, I've tried to use the 'minTime' and 'maxTime' and it gave me an empty calendar.

Is there any workaround that you guys know about ?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean from today 6:00am to next day 5:30am ?

Comment: Actualy,Change the day's hour range from 00:00 - 23:59 to 06:00am - 05:59am.

Comment: Can someone try this question?

Comment: each column in the agenda grid is designed to represent a day. Your suggest time range falls across two days, so bluntly, no it's not possible. Consider whether this is really the ideal way to present such information...why do you want this, exactly? I'm guessing it's going to be related to night shifts or something? But strictly, if something is happening at 2am on Wednesday, then it is happening on Wednesday - it is not, logically, part of Tuesday.

Comment: Consider whether redefining what a "day" means is really a good idea, or might confuse people - if you then look at the calendar and see 2am "Tuesday", can you truly be sure it means Tuesday and not Wednesday? It could get messy very easily. However, if you really really want to do this, then your only options as far as I can see are 1) make a totally [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) - a big and complicated task, not to be undertaken lightly ...

Comment: ... 2) perhaps you could try to use the Basic or List view with a totally custom [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange), 3) do the same as option 2 but using the [Timeline](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) view in the premium Scheduler plugin. One thing is for sure, you can't achieve it using the Agenda view.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to answer from the comment.

Looking at your requirement I think there is only one option, you have to change the code of the plugin. I can tell you that inside function "buildSkeleton" it creates the dom with css "fc-slot" there it format the time before it shown in UI. You have to change there probably to meet your requirement.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for the answer. Your answer is well known to me. I did some hardcoded changes. The grid shows from 6 to 6 but I'm having problem with events creation after 23:59, becuase logically it's on the next day. A bigger issue will be when there will be a newer version, that's why I've asked hopefully there's a nice way to figure this out...:)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround will be allowing event creation until next hours on the next day. I'm doing this by very little code changes, find the following code on your `fullcalendar.js`,

```
function slotSelectionMousedown(ev) {
```

and find where it says,

```
if (cell && cell.col == origCell.col && !getIsCellAllDay(cell)) {
```

then remove `cell.col == origCell.col` so it will be `if (cell && !getIsCellAllDay(cell)) {`,

then on your fullCalendar init call, set `selectHelper` to `false` or don't define it at all.

EDIT: add demo (select 'Futsal'), http://buking.my/Galaxy

Comment: [link]http://uvision.co.il/fradar/scheduler/demos/external-dragging.html - As you can see it didn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The above code is only for event creation using mouse selection, set `selectable` to `true` and add `select` callback function.

Comment: Added demo from my project.